# Adding a network printer with C#

Tags: c#, wmi

I've been building a program to easily configure newly imaged computers (setting DNS servers, IP address, gateway, adding to AD, adding optional printers, etc). I had it working in PowerShell, but I've been trying to port it to C#, mainly to combine lots of small scripts in one, add a nice user interface, and as practice to get better at C#. It's been going well so far, but I've been having some trouble with adding a printer.

Here's the PowerShell script I was using to configure the network printer:

```
Add-PrinterPort -name ESDPRT500 -PrinterHostAddress $ReceiptPrinterIP
Set-Printer -Name "EPSON TM-T88IV Receipt" -PortName ESDPRT500
```

I've been looking at the following C# code, but it appears to only set a printer by TCP/IP port, whereas I believe my port is under "EPSON Port Handler"?

```
ManagementClass portClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort");
ManagementObject portObject = portClass.CreateInstance();
portObject["Name"] = portName;
portObject["HostAddress"] = "174.30.164.15";
portObject["PortNumber"] = portNumber;
portObject["Protocol"] = 1;
portObject["SNMPCommunity"] = "public";
portObject["SNMPEnabled"] = true;
portObject["SNMPDevIndex"] = 1;
PutOptions options = new PutOptions();
options.Type = PutType.UpdateOrCreate;             
portObject.Put(options);
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction given how my printer is configured? I've found examples for installing drivers and adding printers via TCP/IP port #s, but haven't had much luck with this. Thanks!

Comment: First thing I'd try is configure via powershell and then read the settings with c#. Then change the "setup-code" to reflect those, remove printer and try setup via c# ...

Comment: PowerShell documentation for `Add-PrinterPort` says you are creating a TCP/IP printer port using the default TCP port number with that code.

Comment: I think you should use `Win32_Printer` class and then call and then invoke the method `AddPrinterConnection`